# Weird Inequality-limit error

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis

I have made the following conclusion for a problem set.
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \left| (3n)!^{1/n^2}\right| \leq \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{1}{3n} * \sum_{i=1}^{3n} (i)^{\frac{3}{n}}\right| \\
= \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left| \frac{1}{3n} \right| * \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \left| \sum_{i =1 }^{3n}  i^{\frac{3}{n}} \right| \\
= \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{1}{3n} \right| * \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \left| \sum_{i=1}^{3n} 1 \right| \\ 
= \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{3n}{3n} \right|= \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}1
$$
I know that there certainly are some issues from the second statement onwards with the idea of pulling the limits out and putting them back in again. I think(?) that there is an error with this but I can't seem to pinpoint exactly what it is. Could someone help me out here?

Additionally, my question is whether there would be a way to resolve this error by editing the solution in the "spirit" of what I want to achieve.

Any insights would be welcome.

Comment: What did you do in the first step? Also, all your limits are with $x$ but $x$ doesn't appear inside.

Comment: Power mean inequality. I believe that it should be correct (the problem arises from the second step onwards)

Comment: It's not clear how $$\lim_n \sum_{i=1}^{3n}i^{3/n} = \lim_n \sum_{i=1}^{3n} 1$$. And moreover, even if it's correct, you now have $\lim a_n b_n = \lim a_n \lim b_n$ where $a_n$ is not convergent, which is not valid.

Comment: @BenjaminWang edited thanks

Comment: @AndrewZhang I was trying to convert the $i$ values to a power of zero so that I could resolve it to $3n$. This part is tenuous obviously (and I think wrong?) but I think there might be a way out from there?

Comment: @AndrewZhang which part involves the $ \lim a_n b_n $ which you had talked about?

Comment: second to last line

Comment: Also, numerical experiments do not suggest your computation with the sum is correct.

Comment: @AndrewZhang yes that's the issue, though is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @AndrewZhang from the first line onwards?

Comment: The second line is already wrong because you used $\lim a_nb_n = \lim a_n \lim b_n$ without convergence. The first thing I would try whenever I see a factorial is definitely Stirling's approximation.

Comment: @299792458 Did any of us answer your question?

Comment: Not exactly I don’t think so?

Answer (score 1):

Note that by the inequality between the geometric and arithmetic means,
$$
(3n)!^{1/n^2 }  = \sqrt[n]{{1^{1/n} 2^{1/n}  \cdots (3n)^{1/n} }} \le \frac{1}{{3n}}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{3n} {i^{1/n} } .
$$
I do not see why you got $i^{3/n}$. Then
$$
\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{3n} {i^{1/n} } =\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{3n} \exp \left( {\frac{{\log i}}{n}} \right)= \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{3n} {\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{\log i}}{n}} \right)} \right)} =3n+\mathcal{O}(\log n),$$
or just note that
$$
3n \le \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{3n} {i^{1/n} }  \le 3n (3n)^{1/n}.
$$

Comment: I think that the bounds should be tighter? This suggest that the limits are at infinity

Comment: No, it gives that the limit of the upper bound is $1$. Think about it again. Don't forget to divide the final double inequality by $3n$.

Comment: @299792458 So, what do you say?

Answer (score 1):

$1<(3n)!<(3n)^{3n}$ and so, $1<\big((3n)!\big)^{1/n^2}\leq (3n)^{3/n}=\big(3^{1/n}n^{1/n}\big)^3\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}1$

Answer (score 0):

Taking log-limits and applying Stirling's formula, one has
$$\lim \frac{1}{n^2}\log[(3n)!] = \lim \frac{1}{n^2}\log[\sqrt{6\pi n}(3n/e)^{3n}] = \lim \frac{1}{2n^2}\log(6\pi n)+\frac{3}{n}\log(3n/e) = 0$$
Hence the initial limit is = 1.

Comment: Is it possible to work without Stirling?

Comment: Given that you know the answer is 0, you can try to play around with series. I'm not sure if it will work, but you can apply the root or ratio test, and if it's <1, you can conclude.